# Fisherfaces/Linear Discriminat Analysis - What are those faces supposed to be?

Tags: pca, image-processing, discriminant-analysis, computer-vision, latent-dirichlet-alloc

I see a lot of weird blue/gray/green faces when I search for "firsherfaces" at Google.
I see faces like this and my question is simple: What are those faces supposed to be?

Are they some kind of like "average" images? Why grey color?

[image]

Here we have blue color. Why does these "ghost" faces mean? Why does they look like that?

[image]